# Arrays show up in Xcode 4 debugger as empty even though they aren't

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, xcode4

I had been having some issues debugging some code, so I wrote this little piece to test it out:

```
NSMutableArray *output = [NSMutableArray array];
while (true) {
    NSMutableArray *input = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        [input addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
    }
    [output addObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:input]];
    NSLog(@"%@, %@", input, output);
}
```

I stuck a breakpoint on the line with the `NSLog` and found out some interesting stuff. Going into the variable view, I opened up input and it correctly showed it as being filled with NSNumber objects. I then opened up output, which correctly showed as containing one array. However, upon expanding this array, it showed as being empty.

The NSLog, however, showed a different story. It correctly displayed the multidimensional output array as containing arrays filled with NSNumbers. Do multidimensional arrays not work with the variable preview in the debugger? Here's an image of the problem:

[image]

I'm utterly baffled by this. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: I can expand each subarray, but it's being treated as a generic object rather than an array (only showing the `isa` pointer)...

Comment: @jtbandes Yeah, that happens to me too sometimes. I have no idea why, though. It doesn't make much sense, since the type clearly says `__NSArrayI *`. Time to file a bug report!

Comment: Yep, I think that's the answer to your question :)

Comment: @Jake King: Please copy the Radar to http://www.openradar.me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have filed bug report on this to Apple for several versions of Xcode and back in the Project Builder days. It has always been reported as a duplicate. So obviously it is a known bug, but of low priority or very hard to fix.

The same issue exist with the other container classes like `NSDictionary` and `NSSet` as well, so it not specific to `NSArray`.

I suggest you file a report as well over at http://bugreport.apple.com to put more pressure on the issue. And in the mean time rely on `po` or `NSLog` for most of the container classes debugging needs.